# Machine Learning to recognize important words in a sentence

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I want to use machine learning to extract rock-climbing related names/locations from a sentence. I've already "classified" a bunch of data like this:

```
Bouldering in Central Park!!||Central Park
Not the best angle but check out that latch!!! Golden Bowl (V7) in Squamish||Golden Bowl||Squamish  
Does anyone have a used crash pad for sale?||
```

(where I have a sentence followed by `||` then all the names/locations (separated again by `||`)

I'm looking at using ML.NET for this since I'm most familiar with C#, but can't seem to find out how to get started. I think the [Iris classification example](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/MulticlassClassification_Iris) is probably the closest to my situation? But I'm not sure

Any suggestions for what classification model to use in ML.NET? Or a different language/framework to use?

Comment: Are you wanting to do named entity recognition?

Comment: Not sure exactly what that means but I want to extract these names out of the sentence. Don't need to verify them at all - just extract the strings from the sentence

Comment: I think you saw the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/630) already for this in ML.NET, but it's currently not available. I would recommend LUIS but that may require some more manual work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily try some pre-trained NER algorithms like Stanford's or Spacy. Probably, they will not become sufficient for you so at that step you need to determine your entity types and make some labeling to train your own NER algorithm.

You can start to check out [Stanford NER](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) and [Spacy NER](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer) module.

Edit: You can change classifier type to take different results.

Example result on Stanford Online Demo Tool:

[image]